# Interpolate values in QGIS attribute table

Tags: qgis, qgis-3, interpolation

I've got a point shapefile of river sonar data. It got only two fields: `id` and `depth`. I want to interpolate `depth` of selected 40 points (arranged by `id`)  value from 1.49 to 1. Any idea how can I do it with `QGIS` Field Calculator?

I'm using `QGIS 3.10`

[image]

For now I've got only one lame solution:

```
1.5 - @row_number/100
```

[image]

I'm sure that more elegant and mathematical approach exists.

Comment: Have you tried the available interpolation tools? If so, how do they not suite your needs?

Comment: @Erik sure, I've tried. Moreover basemap on the first picture is the product of Ordinary Kriging. However my need is to modify input data for interpolation tools. So I want to make some "fake" cross sections to make kriging result better